# Google Play Games Services unlocking multiple achievements with the same increment counter

Tags: google-play-games

I have a game and would like to add some achievements.
In this example lets say there are the following:

- Won 5 Games
- Won 10 Games
- Won 100 Games

These 3 achievements share the same counter. But as far as I understand I need to create 3 different incremental achievements and post each of them if a game was won.

The only other alternative I see is, don't make incremental achievements and count locally.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, I recently asked a similar question. I was wondering how you went about adding another achievement (ex: Won 1000 Games) while keeping the same counter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876926/how-should-i-deal-with-adding-new-incremental-achievements

I thought I'd ask you since it seems you've probably already had experience with this.

Answer (score 4):

Your first assumption is correct. You would need to create three different incremental achievements and increment each one of them separately.

That said, this is normal and expected behavior. If you're worried about being throttled for hitting the service too much, the "increment three different achievements at once" quota is much more lenient than the "increment the same achievement three times in a row", so you should be fine. Plus, the Play Games library might be smart enough to submit this as a single batch call on your behalf.